# How to implement an abstraction layer over VxWorks to provide handles for exception handling & memory management?

Tags: vxworks

I have just started working on VxWorks. I am currently working on the following :-

I need to create a framework which will encompass exception handling & memory management (detecting null pointer usage, for instance). All in all, it will be like an abstraction layer over the operating system. This framework will be in the form of a downloadable kernel module. Unit tests (also DKM's) would draw from this framework.

I want to manipulate the exception handlers & handle them myself, but I don't know how.

The ED&R component needs to be configured with the kernel image in order to work with certain API'S (if i understand correctly), but if its a DKM which is already in kernel space, doesn't it have complete access to the memory (RAM, persistent memory) & hence can directly gain access ?

Can you provide me with some guidelines as to how I should go about achieving my objective ?

Currently, when an exception occurs, after displaying some details, the task stops & I get a prompt to debug the module. Afterwards, to see the core dump, I use the command edrShow.

What I want to do is, get rid of the debug prompt & after the task stops, display the core dump to the user without having to explicitly issue the command.

I did look into edrStub.c (edrKernelFatalPolicyHandler method) but I haven't been able to figure out how to manipulate it to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're talking about is wanting to implement some kind of extension to the exception mechanism.
ED&R already deals with the conditions you mentioned fairly well. An offending task will typically be suspended so that you could hook up a debugger to it.

If you don't like the default handling of an exception, then you can modify the code located in comp/src/vxworks/edrStub.c (I think that's where it's at).  You could then implement your own function to handle fatal exceptions.

If you want to deal with specific exceptions, the you could use the excLib to plug in your own exception handler, but you really want to know what you're doing...

As for putting stuff in DKMs, the easiest thing to do is to have predefined function pointers for some specific functionality.  If the function pointer is set, then you call that function otherwise, you call the regular code.
In the DKM, there is usually some dkmInit() function that sets the function pointers.

So for example:

```
void regularExceptionHandler() {
   if (__myExceptionHandler != NULL) {
       __myExceptionHandler();
       return;
   }
```

Of course, __myExceptionHandler has to be part of the base vxWorks kernel image.
This is a pattern used often in vxWorks.